# Ruby alternative to void return type

Tags: ruby, void, return-type

My experience is in C-based languages (C, C++, Java, C#) where the return type of a function can be void, i.e no return. But in Ruby, it appears that every function returns something. I was wondering what to return in Ruby for a method that wouldn't return anything in Java or C++. My best guesses would be either nil or the object that contains the method (for chaining) or just ignore whatever happens to be at the end, but I can't seem to find any information on this.

What's an alternative to void in Ruby?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put

```
return nil
```

in the last statement in method.

Or simply

```
nil
```

Comment: The empty function (`def foo; end`) also returns `nil` implicitly.

Comment: @Zoidberg that is true but any practical use?

Comment: Well, to be consistent I would return `nil` from a function returning "void" too.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.1 empty methods no longer return `nil`.
     
[source](http://franck.verrot.fr/blog/2013/08/21/method-definitions-in-ruby-2-1-0-will-not-be-void-anymore/)

Comment: @Dimid That is different question. `a=def foo;end;` and `b=foo()`. You are talking about how a is `:foo`, but we are talking about how b is nil

Answer (score 1):

nil is not the same as void. You can set a variable to nil, but you cannot set it to void. If a function returns nil it can be assigned to a variable with no error, but try that with a void function (in java or some such language that supports void functions) and the compiler will bark. I'm not a ruby super-expert, but I can find no indication that the concept of void is supported. All functions return something, even if it's nil. If this is incorrect then I hope someone with more knowledge of ruby can provide a counterexample.

A variable, especially in ruby where everything is an object, is a thing with a name and a place to store an address that points to an object somewhere on the heap. Setting a variable to nil means setting its pointer to the one and only instance of NilClass. (true and false are similar; there are single instance of TrueClass and FalseClass.)

I realize that C has a thing called void pointers. This is an entirely different use of the word "void". A void pointer does in fact contain an address and point to something. Let's ignore these for now; I'm only mentioning them to head off unfruitful retorts. We're focusing on *functions* in ruby that literally return *nothing*, which do not exist as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want nothing to be returned, yes you can use return nil . But why?

By not assigning a function call to a variable, you can blissfully forget what has been returned. That returned value will be stored no where and will be lost in garbage collection.

Comment: If you don't at least think about what the last expression in the method evaluates to you may accidentally leak information about the implementation of the method and people may start to rely on that, even if your documentation says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of Ruby, [RBS supports `void`](https://github.com/ruby/rbs/wiki/Writing-Signatures-Best-Practices#prefer-void-over-untyped).

If you can't use RBS, you can write your own `Void` object fairly easily using `method_missing`. It doesn't prevent assignment, but it does make debugging easier.

````rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Responds to all messages by raising Void::Error.
#
# Use for methods that only produce side-effects and do not return anything.
# The meaning is the same as in C or Java.
#
# ```
# def void_method
#   # do side-effect
#   Void.new
# end
#
# unintentional_assignment = void_method
# # much later ..
# unintentional_assignment.foo
# # => Void::Error (Void from void_method.rb received: foo)
# ```
class Void
  class Error < RuntimeError
  end

  def initialize
    @instantiation_source_location = caller[1] || 'Source unknown'
  end

  def method_missing(method)
    raise(
      Error,
      format(
        'Void from %s received: %s',
        @instantiation_source_location,
        method
      )
    )
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(*)
    true
  end
end
````